# Latest Desktop Firefox recognized as touch device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

has anyone noticed that on the last version of Desktop Firefox, it is recognized as a touch device?

I am using the script below:

```
function isTouch() {
  try{ document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); return true; }
  catch(e){ return false; 
}
}

if (isTouch()) {
  alert('I am touch device!')
}
```

The script has given me flawless results up until the latest version of Desktop Firefox. Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

Thanks everyone for your time!

edit: False alarm people. I have no idea what went wrong, I tried resetting preferences, disabled all extensions but had no luck.

I finally solved the issue by REFRESHING firefox (lost all my extensions though and had to reinstall).

Thanks for everybody's efforts and sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: A browser is never recognized as a device! The JS API returns the features of the underlying system – which may have a touchscreen (like the modern Thinkpads, which have a keyboard and a touchscreen).

Comment: Considering that Windows is now installed on touch-based laptops and that even Ubuntu these days work with touchscreen laptops it's not surprising that desktop browsers should enable touch events.

Comment: `document.createEvent("TouchEvent")` > 
`NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported` , FF 38.05

Comment: The thing is that it didn't happen up to the latest version of Firefox. Previous versions had indicated correct results concerning desktop version of firefox recognising touch events

Answer (score 1):

You are just checking if you can create a specific type of event, not really if you are currently on a touch device.

Here is a more complete isTouchDevice function, which I wrote some time ago based on the core of Modernizr.

```
/**
 * Detect if the current device is a touch device.
 * Inspired by Modernizr and hardcore streamlined.
 */
function isTouchDevice() {
    var bool;
    if( ('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch ) {
        bool = true;
    }
    else {
        var fakeBody = document.createElement( 'fakebody' );
        fakeBody.innerHTML += '<style>@media (touch-enabled),(-webkit-touch-enabled),(-moz-touch-enabled),(-o-touch-enabled){#touchtest{top:42px;position:absolute}}</style>';
        document.documentElement.appendChild( fakeBody );

        var touchTestNode = document.createElement( 'div' );
        touchTestNode.id = 'touchtest';
        fakeBody.appendChild( touchTestNode );
        bool = touchTestNode.offsetTop === 42;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will test! @feeela, does it recognise correctly all kinds of devices? Including touch-screen laptops, etc?

Comment: using `document.createEvent("TouchEvent")` does return an error in latest FF, so while this script may be more comprehensive, I suspect it will still return true for OPs tests, as they likely have Touch device and not know.

Comment: @Anthony testing on my desktop as I have always done.

Comment: Then I'm guessing your config has something going on that makes it not throw an error for the event type.

Comment: Even with this script firefox gives me POSITIVE touch results. :/

Comment: For example, if I go to `about.config` and change `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` to `1` from `0`, I don't get an error for `document.createEvent("TouchEvent")`

Comment: @scooterlord Mmmh, we have tested that one a year ago on at least ten different mobile devices and those desktop browsers that were current in 2014; maybe that really is a bug in Fx…

Comment: That's why I am trying to figure out what's wrong. I verified that my Firefox has 'simulate touch events:off'. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Ubuntu latest version (38.0) gives correct results, Windows (38.0.5) does not

Comment: Is any of you on Windows and can verify the issue on latest 38.0.5? Just to make sure it's not a configuration error of some sort?

Comment: @scooterlord Just fresh installed 38.0.5 on Windows, mine is not alerting that it is a touch device. It is returning false from isTouch();

Comment: @DasBeasto thanks. I fixed the problem although I wasnt been able to pinpoint it

Comment: Then how did you fix it?

Comment: thx @Anthony, changing dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled from 0 to 1 made that FF is not positive on touch testing

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, and maybe some people will benefit from the information.

In my case, the Touch events were always detected as positive by Modernizr in Firefox desktop, even if they weren't fired.

In the end, I realized that 'dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled' had a value of '1' even if I didn't set it myself.
It was actually switched on by the "Touch" button in Responsive Design View, but never switched back to '0' even after disabling the Touch events with the very same button.

So I've reported a bug to Mozilla : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1188270

You will find a test case there.

Basically, the only solution I had to go back to normal is to change manually the value of 'dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled' to '0' in 'about:config'.
And I'm now aware that by enabling Touch events in the Responsive Design View, I will have to manually switch it back after.

Hope this can help some people !